# Spring SAML: SAMLException: Unsupported request

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am getting

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Unsupported request
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.getBinding(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:265) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl.retrieveMessage(SAMLProcessorImpl.java:172) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:1.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 62 more exception
```

while testing SSO between SP and client IdP.

According to the `org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl#getBinding(org.opensaml.ws.transport.InTransport)` method source code, this exception is thrown when suitable message decoder was not found.

In my security context I have defined next bindings:

```
<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Can anyone helps me to understand why it is being happening?

**UPDATE**:

If I use http://idp.ssocircle.com as an IdP everything works fine, the issue occurs only when I am trying to link with a different IdP.

Here is debug log:

```
2019-03-04 16:46:42.315 DEBUG [211 default task-43][ExceptionTranslationFilter] Calling Authentication entry point.
2019-03-04 16:46:42.315 DEBUG [211 default task-43][ChainingMetadataProvider] Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.315 DEBUG [211 default task-43][AbstractMetadataProvider] Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.315 DEBUG [211 default task-43][AbstractMetadataProvider] Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.315 DEBUG [211 default task-43][AbstractMetadataProvider] Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.316 DEBUG [211 default task-43][AbstractMetadataProvider] Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.316 DEBUG [211 default task-43][ChainingMetadataProvider] Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.316 DEBUG [211 default task-43][AbstractMetadataProvider] Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of com:my:app
2019-03-04 16:46:42.316 DEBUG [211 default task-43][KeyStoreCredentialResolver] Building credential from keystore entry for entityID apollo, usage type UNSPECIFIED
2019-03-04 16:46:42.316 DEBUG [211 default task-43][KeyStoreCredentialResolver] Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
2019-03-04 16:46:42.317 DEBUG [211 default task-43][EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry] Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
2019-03-04 16:46:42.317 DEBUG [211 default task-43][KeyStoreCredentialResolver] Building credential from keystore entry for entityID apollo, usage type UNSPECIFIED
2019-03-04 16:46:42.317 DEBUG [211 default task-43][KeyStoreCredentialResolver] Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
2019-03-04 16:46:42.317 DEBUG [211 default task-43][EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry] Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
2019-03-04 16:46:42.318 DEBUG [211 default task-43][StaticBasicParserPool] Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing'
2019-03-04 16:46:42.318 DEBUG [211 default task-43][StaticBasicParserPool] Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion'
2019-03-04 16:46:42.318 DEBUG [211 default task-43][StaticBasicParserPool] Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl'
2019-03-04 16:46:42.319 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAMLContextProviderImpl] No IDP specified, using default AAMC-External
2019-03-04 16:46:42.319 DEBUG [211 default task-43][ChainingMetadataProvider] Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: AAMC-External
2019-03-04 16:46:42.319 DEBUG [211 default task-43][AbstractMetadataProvider] Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of AAMC-External
2019-03-04 16:46:42.319 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAMLUtil] Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAMLEntryPoint] Processing SSO using WebSSO profile
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
2019-03-04 16:46:42.320 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
2019-03-04 16:46:42.321 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
2019-03-04 16:46:42.321 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SAML2MetadataHelper] Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
2019-03-04 16:46:42.321 DEBUG [211 default task-43][WebSSOProfileImpl] Using default consumer service with binding urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
2019-03-04 16:46:42.321 DEBUG [211 default task-43][BaseMessageEncoder] Beginning encode message to outbound transport of type: org.opensaml.ws.transport.http.HttpServletResponseAdapter
2019-03-04 16:46:42.321 DEBUG [211 default task-43][HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder] Deflating and Base64 encoding SAML message
2019-03-04 16:46:42.321 DEBUG [211 default task-43][BaseMessageEncoder] Marshalling message
2019-03-04 16:46:42.323 DEBUG [211 default task-43][HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder] Building URL to redirect client to
2019-03-04 16:46:42.323 DEBUG [211 default task-43][HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder] Generating signature with key type 'RSA', algorithm URI 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1' over query string 'SAMLRequest=fVJNb9swDP0rAu%2B2bNfNFiFOka0rVqBDg9jdYTdGZhIVtuSJctb9%2BymJi3aXHgW9L%2FJxcfPSd%2BJIno2zFeRpBoKsdq2x%2BwqemrvkM9wsF4x9VwxqNYaD3dDvkTiISLSsLj8VjN4qh2xYWeyJVdCqXv14UEWaqcG74LTrQKyYyYdo9dVZHnvyNfmj0fS0eajgEMKgpNxjoD%2F4N0XsdTpiSDuDhp3VyKl2vcRhSCaMPLnLun4EcRsjGYvhPMZJiaNUhHLKAfdxmoue83vpBooZT7QNtcaTDrKngKvow%2FLbSyBvsZOmHUDcOa%2FpPHUFO%2ByYQNzfVoBlSUTb50%2FFbq6f5%2BX1rN1e77bzfKbNYZZHEK%2BR2RzpjcY80r2NYWyooMjyeZJdJVnZFLkqZ6os0qsi%2FwViPe3qi7GXDj5a7PYCYvW9adbJ%2BrFuQPx87TICYGpOnd39%2B8o%2BFsbXnmAZV66mBqgdFQ8L%2BV5zOT3%2FP47lPw%3D%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1'
2019-03-04 16:46:42.323 DEBUG [211 default task-43][JCEMapper] Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
2019-03-04 16:46:42.323 DEBUG [211 default task-43][JCEMapper] Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
2019-03-04 16:46:42.324 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SigningUtil] Computing signature over input using private key of type RSA and JCA algorithm ID SHA1withRSA
2019-03-04 16:46:42.327 DEBUG [211 default task-43][SigningUtil] Computed signature: 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
2019-03-04 16:46:42.327 DEBUG [211 default task-43][HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder] Generated digital signature value (base64-encoded) Olydix2OP3Ct80/vPnP/mGp53oo4cjLi037UxvohcpPF5C+xwhAtx2G73rqboxCqU/2+gmsLEEeAic3PXOCBOmsTR9UyohJuUcCPvAnkK5hEoR+0aUozDgVlIqKALnw0GNfW+8roNHL3oVAAg2QjtH/NmPbluMpkXvFauP18bYto3pqMpbs9t4h/pdWmoVcUovlC8TbIN+El6P0m+sekDQqlGf2KnMFffJKCyna+ILFqa6gNXnXHhvqWLyYVkqmf2U4JSc7kBvYqX9gCa+wR0hvCgj9baNnkV0D08oRaCljw5LKwRrZkgRBi3lxCzEu7SepRurCjnKfnisw//7sedA==
2019-03-04 16:46:42.328 DEBUG [211 default task-43][HstsHeaderWriter] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@550312e6
2019-03-04 16:46:42.328 DEBUG [211 default task-43][HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the certificate used on Client IdP side. If expired, root certificate expired or using an invalid algorithm, it will be rejected.